# Override python's float for inexact comparison - hash implementation

Tags: python, hash, floating-point, equality, floating-accuracy

I run into an interesting problem - here is an override of float that compares inexactly:

```
class Rounder(float):
    """Float wrapper used for inexact comparison."""
    __slots__ = ()

    def __hash__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def __eq__(self, b, rel_tol=1e-06, abs_tol=1e-12):
        """Check if the two floats are equal to the sixth place (relatively)
        or to the twelfth place (absolutely)."""
        try:
            return abs(self - b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(self), abs(b)),
                                        abs_tol) # could use math.isclose
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented

        ...
```

The requirement is that equal objects have equal hashes - but can't seem to to come up with a formula that represents all Rounder(float) instances that would compare the same (so map them all to the same hash value). Most of the advice in the web is on how to define hash/equals for classes that compare based on some (immutable) attributes - does not apply to this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no valid way to hash these objects. Hashing requires a transitive definition of `==`, which your objects do not have. Even if you did something like `def __hash__(self): return 0`, intransitivity of `==` would still make your objects unsafe to use as dict keys.

Non-transitivity is one of the big reasons *not* to define `==` this way. If you want to do a closeness check, do that explicitly with `math.isclose`. Don't make that operation `==`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think there is no way of defining an inexact equals that is transitive? Maybe using https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio ? It would be ideal not to explicitly use math.isclose (explicit is better than implicit but not always)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: `float.as_integer_ratio` doesn't help. It is technically possible to define a transitive inexact `==` by rounding values, but that just gives you *different* problems.

Comment: Thanks convinced - what would those problems be out of curiosity?

Comment: (by the way it's in sets that turns out I need those - thought I only had comparisons and I would raise from hash - would not use them in dicts)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Two numbers on opposite sides of a rounding boundary get considered unequal, even if they're only one ULP apart.

Comment: Thanks wow what a can of worms - some context on why I need that class https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/commit/d12d8291a0b2ee38fe47ac8c8a556f85862012a0